# discord.py Text sifting

Tags: python, discord.py

Is it possible to delete a message, if the message contain a letter?

I'm writing a counting game and I need to somehow check, if the message doesn't contain the next correct number/contain letters, it must be deleted.

Also, it would be great to allow users make a small commentary after the numbers, like "12 Hello".

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    c_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name='Counting')

    if message.channel.id == 862353141535325:
        messages = await c_channel.history(limit=2).flatten()
        message = re.sub('\D', '', message)
        messages = re.sub('\D', '', messages)

    if message.channel == c_channel and int(messages[1].content) + 1 != int(message.content):
        if message.author.bot: 
            return

        else:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Incorrect.", delete_after=1)
```

But, when I run it it gives me a mistake:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "... Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "... \Bot\Bot.py", line 85, in on_message
    message = re.sub('\D', '', message)
  File "... Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Do you know how to "fix" the mistake or the better code than mine?

Comment: `message = re.sub('\D', '', message)` - your error says - it wants string or bytes-object here but you give `,message)` - `message` there is `discord.Message` class. For string you want to use `message.content`...

And about for "12 Hello" you want to look at in-built standard python `'12 Hello'.startswith('12')` function.

Comment: As I remember, **.startswith** will not work as I want, so no.

Answer (score 0):

`message` is of the class `discord.Message`. The function `re.sub` was expecting a string or bytes-like object. So, you can use:

```python
message = re.sub('\D', '', message.content)
messages = [re.sub('\D', '', msg) for msg in messages]
```

, where `message.content` returns the content of the message.

*Note: You have to enable the `message_content` intent before accessing message content.*

Comment: Okay, I turned on MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT and changed this part:
        message = re.sub('\D', '', message.content)
        messages = re.sub('\D', '', messages.content)

But now I have this error:    
messages = re.sub('\D', '', messages.content)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'content'